# How to choose the test statistic in a hypothesis test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference

I've read somewhere that we often choose an estimator for the parameter in H0, H1 as the test statistic.
I've also noticed that we use the sampling distribution as the chosen distribution very often.

Do we always do this?

Comment: Please specify your question to some more detail as it is too wide to answer in its current state.

Comment: I will give an example. Let's say H0: miu (population mean) = 10. OK, right now what do I do? I just think of the sampling distribution of the sample mean or try to find an unbiased estimator for miu and then find out the distribution of that estimator? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. At heart for a test to work well (at least, to tend to give better chance of rejection under the null than under the alternative), you need the test statistic to behave differently under $H_0$ and $H_1$. In many cases of a hypothesis test involving a single parameter, an obvious test statistic would be some estimator for that parameter -- a reasonable estimator will indeed tend to have a different sampling distribution under the null than under the alternative, since a useful estimator will tend to be close in some sense to the true value and those are different.

   Note that it might not necessarily be the "obvious" estimator such as sample mean for population mean, since once you specify the distribution you're sampling from there may be a much more efficient way to estimate it. Alternatively, you might deliberately construct a robust estimator with the aim of getting something that will perform reasonably even if the assumed distribution from which the data came were somewhat misspecified.

   [You may want to look into [*pivotal quantities*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity) which are often used either as test statistics or as the basis for forming confidence intervals.]

   However,  this is not a requirement -- for example, sometimes with likelihood ratio tests (which are widely used) the test statistic (the ratio of the likelihoods evaluated at their respective maxima) doesn't necessarily correspond to an obvious/explicit estimator of the parameter(s), though the values of the maximum likelihood estimates themselves come into the computation of the likelihood.
2. Naturally, if you have a test statistic, the sampling distribution of that statistic under the null hypothesis is the distribution you use to define the boundary of your rejection region (but the sampling distribution under the alternative shows you which direction the rejection region should go if you want good power against that alternative).

   Sometimes it's hard to evaluate the exact distribution in small samples, and then sometimes people use asymptotic approximations for the sampling distribution.

   We don't necessarily need to be able to explicitly compute the sampling distribution under the null. For example, we might be able to simulate values from the distribution of the test statistic and so get approximate critical values or p-vales as desired. [Or we might not even be willing to specify a distribution for the data and so construct a permutation test/randomization test or a bootstrap test using our test statistic.]

---

To address the title question -- how to choose the test statistic -- there are many ways to do so, as the foregoing suggests. However, generally people seek to have tests with high power, and as a result many tests are based on the [likelihood ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test), because of the [Neyman-Pearson lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%80%93Pearson_lemma).

However, we need not work that way (what if I don't know what distribution my data were drawn from? I almost never do) and can devise almost any statistic we might think would do well - not all choices will lead to tests with good properties, naturally.

Indeed in some cases, particularly when the alternatives may be rather broad (goodness of fit testing is one example), there's almost never a uniformly most powerful test, and then the choice of test statistic might depend on the kinds of alternatives you'd like to be able to pick up, and many different tests might be used in different situations.

--

(Edit in response to comment)

Let's look at the statistic [for a one sample test of variance](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda358.htm) under sampling from a normal distribution. ($H_0: \sigma^2 = \sigma_0^2$ vs $H_1:  \sigma^2 \neq \sigma_0^2$ to take the two-tailed-test specifically)

Now the "obvious" statistic for testing a variance would be $s^2$, but the problem is that the distribution of that test statistic depends on $\sigma^2$, the variance of the population it comes from. [This would not be a problem for a permutation test however - we could actually use $s^2$ as the test statistic without difficulty in that case. But let's leave the case of permutation tests aside.]

We actually only need to worry about the distribution under the null hypothesis, so the distribution of $s^2$ depends on the particular value for $\sigma_0^2$. 
Specifically under sampling from a normal distribution with variance $\sigma_0^2$, $s^2$ has a distribution from the gamma family whose mean is $\sigma_0^2$ and whose variance is $\frac{2}{n-1}\sigma_0^2$.

That's not a problem as such, but it would mean we'd need a different table for every possible $\sigma_0^2$, which would make for very large set of tables (not so much an issue on a computer, where you could just calculate the whole distribution on the fly but it was a big issue when people had to carry tables).

This is where pivotal quantities come in (which I mentioned before). The ratio $Q_0 = s^2/\sigma_0^2$ has a distribution that *doesn't*  depend on the value for $\sigma_0^2$ -- at a given sample size the distribution is always the same no matter which particular value $\sigma_0^2$ has. So now we'd only need a new table for every different sample size. This is a much smaller problem. (Specifically, it has a gamma distribution with mean $1$ and variance $2/(n-1)$ ... this gamma distribution is now a scaled version of a chi-squared distribution. The chi-squared distribution was first derived in relation to the sample variance from a normal distribution by Helmert in 1876, though its name arises because of the notation Karl Pearson used when writing the multivariate normal distribution.)

So then - because the chi-squared was already well known in exactly this context - it would only need us to rescale from $Q_0$ to $Q_1=(n-1)Q_0$ and we'd have that $Q_1$ has a chi-squared distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. Now we're dealing with a situation where some tables already existed, which is even more convenient.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I also try to find the answer to other questions regarding what you said, but I am not used to the 'likelihood' concept. I would like to know why Chi test for Variance [link](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda358.htm) uses that statistic. The mean of that test (which I calculated in order to see if it is an unbiased estimator) is n-1 and not the variance... :(

Comment: @user_anon see the discussion added to the bottom of the answer

Comment: Wow! Thanks again! :) You mentioned "obvious" statistic. Did you mean just taking the statistic from null/alternative hypothesis (here, the variance) or thinking about the statistic from null/alternative hypothesis (here, the variance), checking its expectancy to see if it's an unbiased estimator for the population variance, and then taking this statistic only if it is an unbiased estimator?

Comment: Sorry, I've just come from confidence intervals where you MUST have the sampling distribution of an unbiased estimator and now, here, at hypothesis testing, I just don't know if it is a "must" just like in confidence intervals...

Comment: 1. Unbiasedness doesn't need to come into that consideration at all. You probably want a consistent estimator, but why would unbiasedness matter? I simply meant that if your hypothesis is about population variance, sample variance is the most obvious way to estimate it (and in the case of sampling from a normal, it's a good choice). It would hurt the test in no way at all if we had used the biased ML estimator $s_n^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i (x_i-\bar{x})^2$ instead -- it would just change the scale factor we'd need out the front to make it have a chi-squared distribution.

Comment: 2. You're mistaken - there's no need to use an unbiased estimator with confidence intervals. How did you come by that notion? Is that stated in some book or other? (You might be leaving out some particular condition for example)

Comment: 2. Perhaps no. It is my 'intuition' when I think of confidence intervals: the normal distribution, mu in the middle. So, I thought it should always be like this (the expectancy to be the population mean)

Comment: 'You probably want a consistent estimator?' Both in confidence intervals and hypothesis testing? Why? I would understand this for confidence intervals, but also for hypothesis testing?

Comment: In hypothesis testing, shouldn't I care only of only one thing: my test score not be close to that region for which the are under the curve is say 0.95? From where the idea of estimators (any kind of them)?

Comment: If you're basing your test statistic on an estimator, you'll generall want consistency because otherwise your hypothesis test won't tend to become more powerful as you increase sample size. If you're only doing one test at one sample size that's not a big issue but if you want a test you can use again, it would make sense.

Comment: Please note that comments are for things like clarification of questions or answers, rather than for extended discussion. You might consider whether you need to ask a new question.